# Reducir cantidad de condicionales en una función

Tags: php, validación, condiciones, else

Tengo un inconveniente con utilizar muchos elseif seguidos así de esta manera, hay alguna manera de reducir la cantidad de condicionales y reducirlos máximo a 3 o 2

Lo que estoy haciendo es realizar una validación con información de una base de datos, existen 3 parámetros para traer esa información, por cliente, transporte y deposito, esos serian los parámetros, así el código me funciona correctamente pero no debo mostrarlo de esa manera, este debe tener la menor cantidad de condicionales.

Ya sabrán que para filtrar puede que se pase como parámetro solo el cliente, o el deposito o el transporte, como también el cliente y el deposito o el cliente y el transporte, también puede que exista la opción deposito y transporte o todas a la vez.

Quisiera un poco de su ayuda.

```
public function getFiltersAgile(array $clients, $selectedClient = null, $transportDocument = null, $selectedDeposits = null) {
        $db = DB::connection($this->connection);
        if ((null !== $selectedClient) and (null == $transportDocument) and (null == $selectedDeposits)) {
          $pipeline = array(
            array(
              '$match' => array(
                '$and' => array(
                  array('cliidxxx' => array('$in' => $clients)),
                  array('cliidxxx' => array('$eq' => $selectedClient))
                )
              )
            ),
            array(
              '$project' => array(
                'docestul' => 1,
              )
            )
          );
        }
        elseif ((null !== $selectedClient) and (null !== $transportDocument) and (null == $selectedDeposits)) {
          $pipeline = array(
            array(
              '$match' => array(
                '$and' => array(
                  array('cliidxxx' => array('$in' => $clients)),
                  array('cliidxxx' => array('$eq' => $selectedClient)),
                  array('dtrdtrxx' => array('$eq' => $transportDocument))
                )
              )
            ),
            array(
              '$project' => array(
                'docestul' => 1,
              )
            )
          );
        }
        elseif ((null !== $selectedClient) and (null == $transportDocument) and (null !== $selectedDeposits)) {
          $pipeline = array(
            array(
              '$match' => array(
                '$and' => array(
                  array('cliidxxx' => array('$in' => $clients)),
                  array('cliidxxx' => array('$eq' => $selectedClient)),
                  array('depidxxx' => array('$eq' => $selectedDeposits))
                )
              )
            ),
            array(
              '$project' => array(
                'docestul' => 1,
              )
            )
          );
        }
        elseif ((null == $selectedClient) and (null !== $transportDocument) and (null == $selectedDeposits)) {
          $pipeline = array(
            array(
              '$match' => array(
                '$and' => array(
                  array('cliidxxx' => array('$in' => $clients)),
                  array('dtrdtrxx' => array('$eq' => $transportDocument))
                )
              )
            ),
            array(
              '$project' => array(
                'docestul' => 1,
              )
            )
          );
        }
        elseif ((null == $selectedClient) and (null !== $transportDocument) and (null !== $selectedDeposits)) {
          $pipeline = array(
            array(
              '$match' => array(
                '$and' => array(
                  array('cliidxxx' => array('$in' => $clients)),
                  array('dtrdtrxx' => array('$eq' => $transportDocument)),
                  array('depidxxx' => array('$eq' => $selectedDeposits))
                )
              )
            ),
            array(
              '$project' => array(
                'docestul' => 1,
              )
            )
          );
        }
        elseif ((null == $selectedClient) and (null == $transportDocument) and (null !== $selectedDeposits)) {
          $pipeline = array(
            array(
              '$match' => array(
                '$and' => array(
                  array('cliidxxx' => array('$in' => $clients)),
                  array('depidxxx' => array('$eq' => $selectedDeposits))
                )
              )
            ),
            array(
              '$project' => array(
                'docestul' => 1,
              )
            )
          );
        }
        elseif ((null !== $transportDocument) and (null !== $selectedDeposits) and (null !== $selectedClient)) {
          $pipeline = array(
            array(
              '$match' => array(
                '$and' => array(
                  array('cliidxxx' => array('$in' => $clients)),
                  array('cliidxxx' => array('$eq' => $selectedClient)),
                  array('dtrdtrxx' => array('$eq' => $transportDocument)),
                  array('depidxxx' => array('$eq' => $selectedDeposits))
                )
              )
            ),
            array(
              '$project' => array(
                'docestul' => 1,
              )
            )
          );
        }
        else{
          $pipeline = array(
            array(
              '$match' => array(
                '$and' => array(
                  array('cliidxxx' => array('$in' => $clients))
                )
              )
            );
        }
      }
```

Espero que esta información sea mas que suficiente.

Comment: Podrias usar un ``switch`` que es como el ``case``, un bloque de codigo para cada caso, escribirías practicamente el mismo codigo pero el sistema no haria tantas evaluaciones. Aca tenes un ejemplo de diferencia de performance para cada estructura de decision http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SpeedTestIfElseSwitch.aspx

Comment: Ademas de lo dicho antes tengo entendido que el IF evalua todas las opciones indistintamente, en cambio el switch solo selecciona la opcion correcta, por lo que optimizaria mucho tu codigo.

Comment: @Mani esa opción no es viable ya que se seguiría repitiendo código, la idea es esa también, no repetir tanto código.

Comment: El problema es que tu método `getFiltersAgile()` es fruto de un mal diseño en alguna parte. Llegados a este punto es imposible resolver tu situación aquí de algún modo que evite código spaghetti sin pasar por soluciones oscuras. La pregunta es: ¿por qué se ha llegado a este punto? ¿por qué no se controla en el diseño de la aplicación de modo que puedas saber con facilidad las opciones que se han elegido para en consecuencia armar el resto del código? Lo que quiero decir es que tu función revela realmente una disfunción en alguna etapa a la cual convendría volver para resolver el problema.

Comment: O simplemente ¿no será que estás tratando de resolver el problema antes de  tiempo? Por ejemplo, ¿qué destino tiene `$pipeline`? ¿no sería mejor verificar el estado final de `$pipeline`, viendo allí lo que existe o no existe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta solo aplicando solo `if` en vez de `elseif`, en donde si es `!= null` se agrega como nuevo elemento.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
  public function getFiltersAgile(array $clients, $selectedClient = null, $transportDocument = null, $selectedDeposits = null) 
{
    $db = DB::connection($this->connection);
        $pipeline = array(
            array(
            '$match' => array(
                '$and' => array(
                    array('cliidxxx' => array('$in' => $clients)),

                )
            ),
            array(
                '$project' => array(
                  'docestul' => 1,
                )
            )
        );
        if(null !== $selectedClient)
            $pipeline['$match']['$and']['cliidxxx']['$eq'] =$selectedClient;
        if(null !== $transportDocument)
            $pipeline['$match']['$and']['dtrdtrxx']['$eq'] =$transportDocument;
        if(null !== $selectedDeposits)
            $pipeline['$match']['$and']['depidxxx']['$eq'] = $selectedDeposits;

    }   
    ?>
```

Comment: ¿Hay dos `if` idénticos?

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por ayudarme con esta inquietud, lo resolvi de la siguiente manera:

```
public function getFiltersAgile(array $clients, array $selectedClient, array $transportDocument, array $selectedDeposits) {
    $db = DB::connection($this->connection);
    $conditions = [];
    $conditions[] = array('cliidxxx' => array('$in' => $clients));
    if (!empty($selectedClient)) {
      $conditions[] = array('cliidxxx' => array('$in' => $selectedClient));
    }

    if (!empty($transportDocument)) {
      $conditions[] = array('dtrdtrxx' => array('$in' => $transportDocument));
    }

    if (!empty($selectedDeposits)) {
      $conditions[] = array('depidxxx' => array('$in' => $selectedDeposits));
    }

    $pipeline = array(
      array(
        '$match' => array(
          '$and' => $conditions,
        )
      ),
      array(
        '$project' => array(
          'docestul' => 1,
        )
      )
    );

    $group = array(
      '$group' => array(
        '_id' => array(
          'docestul' => '$docestul'
        ),
        'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
      )
    );
    array_push($pipeline, $group);
    $collection = $db->selectCollection($this->collection);
    $result_agg = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
    DB::disconnect();
    $response = $result_agg->toArray();
    return $response;
  }
```